# Nginx location issue

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set a longer (30 day) 'expires' header for my (images only) in the /misc-stuff/ directory.

This is what I'm using for my site :

```
# Serve static files directly from nginx
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
   add_header        Cache-Control public;
   add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
   expires           7d;
}
```

I want to be able to keep that code in to handle regular site images, but create a new block to handle the /misc-stuff/ directory.

I have tried :

```
location ^~ /misc-stuff/ {
...
}
```

The problem I'm having now is that my backup .php files in that directory show up as plain text if someone tries to access it.

How do I set it up so ONLY .gif images in the /misc-stuff/ directory are effected?

Comment: Could some explain why adding the ^ and $ is necessary?

Comment: Essentially `^` means start of the line and `$` means end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a good reason for selecting the `^~` literal-string matching prefix? `^~` does not support regular expressions, so what you have now cannot easily be fixed. If, however, you've blindly copied this chunk from elsewhere without understanding it, then you're in luck; change to the `~*` case insensitive regular expression matching prefix, and write a regular expression that matches your needs:

```
location ~* ^/misc-stuff/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
...
}
```

Of course, your `.php` files in that directory might still match another `location` directive; be sure to write a `location` directive that sends those to the PHP interpreter of your choice, if you want them executable. (Or change their permissions to forbid the server to read them, if you want to keep them in that directory for some reason but not execute them or let others read them.)

While the standard [nginx docs on the `location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) are a little lacking, I've found the [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) to be quite good.

Comment: It was a blind copy - copied / pasted the wrong example. I have another location block that passes php to apache. This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: You should anchor that match with ^ at the beginning and $ at the end.